# Cookie not setting in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Thought this was super easy, but I've spent the last half hour trying to figure it out to no avail.

```
$unique_id = uniqid(microtime(),1);

if (is_null($_COOKIE['client_id']))
  {
  setcookie("client_id", $unique_id);
  }
```

**But when I go to check the cookie through $_COOKIE['client_id'], I get a null value.** Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you checking the cookie value on the same request or on a different one?

Comment: Same request, does that matter?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444635/cant-set-cookies-in-php/2444671#2444671 (and/or my edited answer) for why it matters.

Comment: I'd recommend you use `empty` or `!isset` instead of `is_null`. `is_null` will throw a warning if the variable is not set at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _COOKIE array is created when the script initializes, and is then left alone by PHP. Setting a cookie within the script will not magically add it to $_COOKIE. It will only show up on the next script request, or you manually assign it into $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 8):

Cookies have to be set before ANYTHING is outputted. also I've had many problems with cookies before.

Also, see [Can't set cookies in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444635/cant-set-cookies-in-php/2444671#2444671) for explanation why you cant check its existence at the same time as setting it.

Answer (score 2):

You should set cookie with

```
$_COOKIE['key'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah FallingBullets has right. Be affraid when you use UTF8 file encoding - the first chars with is sent to client is UTF8 file head (ď»ż 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF). In this case is  ob-start http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php not work (UTF8 file head is sent before ob-start).

What I describe is probably characteristic of the web server. Try save jour script in ascii encoding.