# setcookie is not setting value in browser in PHP

Tags: php

I try to set cookie using below code in PHP but cookie is not displaying when I check using `print_r($_COOKIE);`

```
$str_zipcode = "20304";
setcookie("zipcode", $str_zipcode, 2147483647);
```

Then I try to set cookie using below code in PHP and cookie is displaying when I check using `print_r($_COOKIE);` But when I refresh browser or close and reopen browser and check cookie value using `print_r($_COOKIE);` then cookie not displaying and that means. Not sure what is wrong I am doing in this code.

```
$str_zipcode = "20304";
$_COOKIE['zipcode'] = $str_zipcode;
```

Below are my laptop configuration.

```
PHP 7
Ubuntu 16.0
Mozilla Firefox 80.0.1
```

EDIT #1
I checked in mobile's chrome browser too and it's behaving same as I mentioned above for my laptop.

Comment: Check your browser settings to make sure it's not set to clear cookies when closing. Make sure you're not using private browsing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie not setting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161490/cookie-not-setting-in-php)

Comment: @Cfreak That doesn't seem to be the problem. That's about checking `$_COOKIE` in the same script process, but this question is about refreshing the page.

Comment: @Barmar, I am not using private browsing and cookies are not deleted when browser is closed. I just checked those settings once again after your comment.

Comment: What if you use a lower expiration time, like `86400 * 365` for 1 year?

Comment: You are trying to set your cookie to a new value after it has already been set! To see the cookie data: $cookie = $_COOKIE['zipcode']; then echo $cookie;

Comment: @Barmar, I tried from 5 minute to 1 day but still no luck.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. Something else must be removing the cookie.

Comment: @SJacks, I tried what you suggested and I checked in browser's Manage Cookie Data but cookie is not available there.

Comment: @RKAhir are you getting any PHP error messages about headers already sent?

Comment: @SJacks, I just checked the error log and I am getting the error you mentioned in your comment (`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`)

Comment: This is your problem. It's because setting a cookie is a header function so you are already sending a header before setting the cookie. This could be to do with a header redirect or something else. If you remove this previous header  your cookie will get set.

Comment: @SJacks, it works now when I move entire code before 2 redirects on page. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

the last parameter for cookie is its expiration date :
eg:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = "John Doe";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    
}
```